# Bootswatch through package manager?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm, bootswatch

I've started a small asp.net core website. For now all JS/CSS that I'm importing are coming from NPM and webpack is here to to pack them together.

I wanted to de deviate from the standard bootstrap template and use [bootswatch paper](http://bootswatch.com/paper/), but I didn't found any package I could import to replace default template.

They say we should just replace the bootstrap.css, but since mine is coming from the package, and will not be in my git repository, they basically advise me to have a second boostrap.css and reference it? But what happens when bootstrap is updated(so is the plugin) do I have to update manually?

I can't imagine this is the best solution. Any idea how I should install bootswatch then? (My website has been generated through `JavascriptServices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Bootswatch from their [github](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch)

Using the following command

The number at the end is the commit hash.

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch.git#95a134434fd0955182e9a938b5e50624e8e143c6
```

Once installed, you will find **Paper** in `/node_modules/bootswatch/paper/`

npmjs.com explains more about downloading from other sources in their [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Ok, but then there is no guarante(dependency) that would require to have the version X of bootstrapper with the version Y of Paper, right? And if you specify the commit hash in the source, how do you update it? Uninstall the previous and install the new one?

Comment: @J4N - The commit would be the guarantee to the version of bootstrap/paper you wish to use, since the versioning would appear in the source files. [bower.json](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/bower.json) for bootstrap version.  Regarding updating, you are correct and can uninstall / install a new one.